# NetworkX Python types issue with weighted graph

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, shortest-path

I am trying to find a shortest path with the following code, however I  keep getting issues with types, tupples and referencing. The original code was from https://gist.github.com/etrain/5736212. Please help. My current error is

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
def output_path(path, g, start="USD"):
    visited = set(start)
    tot = 1.0
    pred = path[start]
    x = start
    while pred not in visited:
        print
        pred, "-->", x, math.exp(-g[pred][x]['weight'])
        tot *= math.exp(-g[pred][x]['weight'])
        visited.add(pred)
        x = pred
        pred = path[pred]

    tot *= math.exp(-g[start][x]['weight'])
    print
    start, "-->", x, math.exp(-g[start][x]['weight'])
    print
    "Total:", tot
```

Path is a set e.g.

```
({'USD': 'BTC', 'JPY': 'BTC', 'EUR': 'BTC', 'BTC': 'USD'}, {'USD': -0.34881793013571283, 'JPY': -4.977374652553437, 'EUR': -0.04449874583834479, 'BTC': 4.496366978018229})
```

PRED, VISITED and START all seem to conflict and give errors or no results.

I dont understand how this is supposed to work? Any help is appreciated.

error:

File "...arbitrage.py", line 27, in output_path pred, "-->", x, math.exp(-g[pred][x]['weight']) File "...\networkx\c‌​lasses\graph.py", line 438, in getitem return self.adj[n] File "...\networkx\c‌​lasses\coreviews.py"‌​, line 82, in getitem return AtlasView(self._atlas[name]) TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Adjustments so far to code:
I have changed the above to this to get it this far...:

```
visited = set([start])
pred = set(path[0])
.....
.....
pred = path[0][pred]
```

These have seemed to have helped, although i dont know if these changes are correct.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: I have added the error message in the main body. I have also made adjustments to the original code I have included as well